# Consolidating a ton of mostly blank columns into one column (Postgres and Python)

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a raw data table with over 500 columns that I am importing to a different database. Most of these columns are null (for example: `session1`, `session2`, `session3` ~ `session120`). I didn't design this table, but there are 3 column types with over 100 columns each. Most would not need to be used unless it was for some very specific analysis or investigation (if ever).

Is there a nice way to combine these columns into a consolidated column which can be 'unpacked' later? I don't want to lose the information in case there is something important.
Here is my naive approach (using pandas to modify the raw data before inserting it into postgres):

```
column_list = []
for val in range(10, 120):
    column_list.append('session' + str(val))
df['session_10_to_120'] = df[column_list ].astype(str).sum(axis=1).replace('', ',', regex = True)\n",
for col in column_list :
    df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I don't want to mess up my `COPY` statements to postgres (where it might think that the commas are separate columns).

Any recommendations? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on what you want to do with these columns, but options include

- arrays
- non-relational storage: hstore, json, xml
- turning the columns into rows in another table